# Passing a JSON object from the background script to the content script in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a JS array in the "background.js" file of my Chrome extension. I converted the JS object to a JSON string to pass it into the "content.js" file but am unable to do so.
Can I be helped with the code to send the JSON object from the "background.js" file and the code to receive the same from the "content.js" file.

```
// This is the important portion of the code present in the background.js file.
console.log("Inside the buttonClicked function");
var titles = [];
var hrefs = [];
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('uqZtlf x0HGk QRiHXd MymH0d maXJsd');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) 
{
    hrefs.push(links[i].href);  // capturing urls
    titles.push(links[i].title); // capturing titles
}
jsonObjectLinks = JSON.stringify(hrefs); // converting the js object to the JSON string
console.log(jsonObjectLinks);
var jsonObjectTitles = JSON.stringify(titles);

// I now wish to pass on the jsonObjectTitles to the content.js file
```

Comment: May you provide a [mcve] of your issue? Otherwise it will be really hard to help

Comment: Have added the important portion of the code in my question, sorry for the inconvenience caused previously.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: have already tried it, but the code gets an error on the 1st line of.   'chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});'

Comment: It means you did something wrong because this code works for everyone else. Shows us your manifest.json and the exact error text.